# I want to translate the string with the function str_to_upper to Spanish but it remains in English

Tags: translation

> Cargamos los paquetes necesarios para ejecutar la función

`library(dplyr)`
`library(stringr)`

> Creamos el marco de datos para ejecutar la función

```
people <- tibble(name = c("Jordi", "Marta", "Laura", "Rodrigo"),
                 gender = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male"),
                 age = c(42, 31, 18, 65))
```

`str_to_upper(people$gender, "sp")`

Answer (score 0):

`str_to_upper` function is not meant to translate actual text from one language to another.
See the documentation: https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/case.html

It just converts the case. The locale parameter is used when there is a different conversion from lower to upper case letter depending on the language.

The documentation states:

```
# Locale matters!
str_to_upper("i") # English
#> [1] "I"
str_to_upper("i", "tr") # Turkish
#> [1] "İ"
```

In order to have actual translations, you have to use a different approach: internationalization or i18n. You might find this link useful: https://blog.logrocket.com/rust-internationalization-localization-and-translation/

Comment: Thanks! I finally understood what were the function and argument locale  for.